# HTMLEditorExtender Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I'm using Nuget latest AjaxControlToolkit ver.16.1.2 and my HTMLEditorExtender is giving this problem when I tried to upload any photo.

The textbox and the HTMLEditorExtender is located inside a repeater in which to be generated multiple controls when a button of the page is clicked and a number specified. Example when user provide 5 and click the button, 5 of the HTMLEditor will be generated.

Below are the errors and also the source. Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks

[image: The error message]
[image: The location of the error generated]
[image: The console output from FireFox]

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxQuestion" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="400px" Width="90%" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="tbxQuestion_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbxQuestion" Enabled="true"
                            OnImageUploadComplete="tbxDummy_HtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete" DisplaySourceTab="true" EnableSanitization="false">
                            <Toolbar>
                                <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
                                <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
                                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
                                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
                                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
                                <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
                                <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
                                <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
                                <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
                                <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
                                <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
                                <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
                                <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
                                <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
                                <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
                                <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
                                <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
                                <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
                            </Toolbar>
                        </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Comment: What is the contents of e in the catch-block?

Comment: Same as the pop up, can't deserialize the data and invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted back to version 7.1213 and it's working now without issue. The latest version is having the issue.